# Finding most recent item in query across duplicate ids

Tags: sql, postgresql

I'm currently attempting to write a query that finds the most recent item across a series of rows that have the same id.

Essentially, the query should be able to see for each duplicate id, what's the latest item in the subgroup.

In the above case, row 1, 3 and 6 should be returned. The data comes from a function that basically finds all actions taken on the service item, and the time it was taken, so I'm attempting to see what was the latest action being made.

Currently, the query I have written uses the last_value and partition by to create the result set. I'm wondering if there's a more performant way to do this, or possibly a more viable solution.

```
select distinct
    x, 
    last_value(t) over (
        partition by x order by t
        range between unbounded preceding and unbounded following
    ) as time
from 
   test_table
```

I'm currently using postgres.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `not exists` as follows:

```
select t.*
from test_table t
Where not exists
(Select 1 from test_table tt
  Where tt.child_service_item_id = t.child_service_item_id
    And tt.action_date > t.action_date)
```

Or quite simple way is `group by` as follows:

```
Select child_service_item_id, max(action_date)
  From test_table
 Group by child_service_item_id
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `distinct on`:

```
select distinct on (child_service_item_id) t.*
from test_table t
order by child_service_item_id, action_date desc;
```